# Password is hashed twice when using before_create and before_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my User model, I have a hash_password method which encrypts the user's password before creating a new user. I am also using this method when a user's password is updated. This is causing the password to be hashed twice.

user.rb:

```
before_create :hash_password
before_update :hash_password

def hash_password
    self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password)
    self.password_confirmation = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password_confirmation)
end
```

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As an improvement, you can replace `before_create :hash_password
before_update :hash_password` with `before_save :hash_password`

Comment: Thank you, it is still hashing the password twice though. Any idea why?

Comment: Yep, this was not a solution. The code you are showings seems well. No issue in this.

Comment: Is there somewhere in your code where you save the object twice? There are "silent saves" like `update_attributes` which call an implicit save

Comment: You might want to add a condition in your callback: `before_save :hash_password, if: Proc.new{ |user| user.changes[:password].present? }`

Comment: This is a workaround, it did not solve the problem in the first place. You should look into that issue until you solved it before it grows and become a bigger problem that what it currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're hashing on save when a new password is entered, but you're also hashing on save when the password is unchanged (and so double-hashing)

You may want to try this, called on `before_save`

```
def hash_password
  return if persisted? && password == User.find(id).password
  self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
  self.password_confirmation = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password_confirmation)
end
```

That means the hashing will only occur on new records or on persisted records where the password has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks `before_create` and `before_update` can be combined/replaced with `before_save`. That is, if you want that functionality. If you only want to call the function when it is being created, then, of course, take out the `before_update` callback.

Update:

This might be some quirks on how you create your `User`. If you call `User.create`, it seems to fire twice, but if you use `User.build` and then `save`, it seems to work, at least according to [this article](http://www.jacoulter.com/2011/12/07/rails-before_save-callback-firing-twice/).

Comment: I replaced these with before_save, but the password is still being hashed twice

Comment: As in, the method is being called twice? How do you know it's being hashed twice? One possibility is that you are hashing the password and confirmation, instead of just the password.

Comment: ... and you're only calling `before_save` once?  If you replaced both `before_create` and `before_update` with separate instances of `before_save` then you're calling `hash_password` twice.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Yes, I only called `before_save` once.

Comment: @RyanK I believe it is hashing twice because after creating a new user, when I attempt to login the password is hashed and then compared against the hash saved in the database, they should match but they do not.

Comment: @RyanK I just confirmed that it is in fact hashing twice. I hashed my password, then entered that hash into a SHA1 generator, and it returned the same hash that is saved in my database.

Comment: If you believe it is hashed twice, try removing the callback altogether. Maybe some other code is silently hashing it for you.

Comment: @RyanK That didn't work. The hashing works fine when i use `before_create` only, it is only causing problems when i add the `before_update` or change it to `before_save`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 before_create :hash_password
 before_update :hash_password
```

With `before_save :hash_password`